# Reusing memory allocated by LodePNG

Tags: c, image-processing, memory-management, lodepng

I am working on an embedded project, I am currently using [LodePNG](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/). This lib works well and quite light weight.

The only problem is that for every PNG load, the memory must be freed. Is there any possibility to reuse the memory allocated by the load function?
I was not able to find such a method in the manual.

The program keeps loading PNG images, so reusing memory allocated for a previous image would be great!

Is there any other way? I need 24bit RGB raw data, I need a lightweight solution, and the code must be platform independent.

Comment: This only applies if the images are the same size, always. Its a big assumption to make. If this is your case, you can go and modify the code to do this.

Comment: All the images are of the same size, or smaller. Indeed a big assumption.

Comment: Being smaller likely may not work. What is the question? If it can be done?: yes. Then?

Answer (score 0):

lodepng allows for custom allocators, see `lodepng.cpp:53`:

```
The malloc, realloc and free functions defined here with "lodepng_" in front
of the name, so that you can easily change them to others related to 
your platform if needed. Everything else in the code calls these. Pass
-DLODEPNG_NO_COMPILE_ALLOCATORS to the compiler, or comment out
#define LODEPNG_COMPILE_ALLOCATORS in the header, to disable the ones here and
define them in your own project's source files without needing to change
lodepng source code. Don't forget to remove "static" if you copypaste 
them from here.
```

I guess you could define an allocator that reuses a fixed memory block.